Regex not working in apache rewritecond
Given the url: https://{SITE}/tgif/flink?search1=scode=atrre%20and%20year=2023&format=USGARS I want to rewrite it to https://{SITE}/tgif/flink/TERO/2023. Where 2023 is the only variable part of the redirect and format or search1 can come in either order.
My apache rewrite rules for this are:
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)format=USGARS [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)search1=scode(?:=|%3D)atrre(?:[\ +]|%20)and(?:[\ +]|%20)year(?:=|%3D)(\d{4}) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^tgif/flink$ /tgif/flink/TERO/%1 [QSD,R=301,L]

The redirect does not work even though the regex validates using other tools, rather it is skipped as if it doesn't exist.  I have dozens of other similar rewrites that work fine.  The only difference I see in this is that this one has = signs in value for the search1 query.  Does someone else see something wrong and/or know how to properly handle this instance?  Does apache handle the extra = signs in some special way that I am not aware of?

The rule looks OK (although could be simplified). There is no special handling of = by Apache. More likely you have a conflict with your existing rules (or you are seeing a cached response). Please edit your question to include your complete .htaccess file with this rule in place. (Aside: You should test first with 302 - temporary - redirects to avoid caching issues.)

Aside: "I want to rewrite it to" - That's a "redirect", not a "rewrite".

I found my answer.  The problem was actually in the RewriteRule line which should have been RewriteRule "^/tgif/flink" "/tgif/flink/TERO/%1" [QSD,R=301,L].

That would imply the rule is being used directly in the server (or virtualhost) config, as opposed to .htaccess or (<Directory> container) - which I had assumed earlier. (The original rule is correct if used in a directory context.) The double quotes are unnecessary here, but in removing the end-of-string anchor then you are matching /tgif/flink<anything> - is that necessary?
